# selectRowAtIndexPath from another UIVIewController not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I am trying to call **selectRowAtIndexPath** on a UITableView that is a subview to the UIViewController I am calling it from.

I have set it up so that when you select a cell it goes grey and thats fine, however I am loading different data sets in and out of the UITableView and when ever a selection is made I am sending that selected NSIndexPath back to the UIViewController. Then when the view is next loaded with the correct data set for the NSIndexPath I call this method from my UIViewController.

```
if (codeIndexPath != nil) {
            [filterViewController.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:codeIndexPath animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle];
}
```

Then in the UITableView class my **cellForRowAtIndexPath** and **didSelectRowAtIndexPath** look like this.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    // Configure the cell...
    NSString *projectDescriptionString = [currentFilterMutableArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = projectDescriptionString;
    if (indexPath == currentlySelectedIndex) {
        cell.highlighted = YES;
    } else if (indexPath == currentlySelectedIndex) {
        cell.highlighted = NO;
    }
    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray;

    // send this data back in the delegate so you can use it to show where the tick is again if you need too.
    currentlySelectedIndex = indexPath;

    [[self delegate] updateInstallTableWithFilter:[currentFilterMutableArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] FilterType:filterType InstallIndex:indexPath];

}
```

When It loads on the screen the correct cell will highlight for a second then go back to white.

### Update

New if statment inside cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
if ([indexPath isEqual:currentlySelectedIndex]) {
        cell.highlighted = YES;
    } else if (![indexPath isEqual:currentlySelectedIndex]) {
        cell.highlighted = NO;
    }
```

I am still receiving the same error.

Comment: You shouldn't be comparing indexPaths with "==", because they're objects. You should use isEqual: instead.

Comment: not only that if and else if are both == lol missed that one.. I updated it.. will show new code in a sec.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UITableViewController has a property called `clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear`.  [From the doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableViewController/clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear):

> When the table view is about to appear the first time it’s loaded, the
>   table-view controller reloads the table view’s data. It also clears
>   its selection (with or without animation, depending on the request)
>   every time the table view is displayed. The UITableViewController
>   class implements this in the superclass method viewWillAppear:. You
>   can disable this behavior by changing the value in the
>   clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear property.

So in that table view controller subclass, in viewDidLoad...

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;
}
```

Comment: wow.. I have been trying so much stuff I got abit lost in it all... oh well I have learnt something new today lets hope I rememver it next time. lol thank you very much for your help.