# SelectedBackgroundView is not shown when tableviewcell is selected programmatically

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I have a `UITableView` and in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method I set the cell's `SelectedBackgroundView` property. When I manually tap on the cell, the background view is properly shown, but when I select the row programmatically, the backgroundview is not seen.

This is how I set the background view:

```
let selectedView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, cell!.frame.size.width, cell!.frame.size.height))
selectedView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.3)
cell!.selectedBackgroundView = selectedView
```

This is how I select the row:

```
slideBarController.tableView.selectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true, scrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.None)
```

Any ideas on how to make the background view visible when selecting the row via code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer in this question:

[selectRowAtIndexPath from another UIVIewController not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23025120/selectrowatindexpath-from-another-uiviewcontroller-not-working)

Simply needed to set the `UITableViewController`'s property `clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear` to false in the `ViewDidLoad` method